# Returning the smallest integer of an increasing function

Tags: python, function, math, equation, minimize

> Write a function `lowest_integer()` which takes 2 input arguments:
>
> - a function `f` representing an increasing function (),
> - a number `fmin`,
>
> and returns an integer `nmin` such that >0 is the smallest
> integer that satisfies ()>.
>
> To test the function we use code like this where we define `f(n)` then
> `print(lowest_integer(f, fmin))` and get the expected output:
>
> ```py
> def f(n):
>     return 2*n
> print(lowest_integer(f, 10))
> ## 6
>
> def f(n):
>     return n**2 + 6*n - 3
> print(lowest_integer(f, 500))
> ## 20
> ```

My attempt at the code:

```py
def lowest_integer(f, fmin):
    f = fmin
    nmin = n + 1
    return nmin
```

I'm having trouble figuring out how to define the function `f(n)` within the `lowest_integer()` function

Comment: You do not need to *define* `f` within `lowest_integer`, you need to *call* it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop through the integers starting at `1`, until you find one that satisfies your condition, in that case, return it:

```
def lowest_integer(f, fmin):
    nmin = 1
    while True:
        if f(nmin) > fmin:
            return nmin
        nmin += 1

def f(n):
    return 2*n
print(lowest_integer(f, 10))

def f(n):
    return n**2 + 6*n - 3
print(lowest_integer(f, 500))
```

Output:

```
6
20
```

This approach, of course, is a naive one, and will be slow if the function `f` is slow and `fmin` is very big, but in general it does good.

A faster approach would be using a library like `sympy` or something, that have functions that use more sophisticated methods and techniques that are suited to these kinds of problems.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it like that :

```
def lowest_integer(f, fmin):
    nmin=1
    while f(nmin)<=fmin :
        nmin += 1
    return nmin
```

You begin with `nmin = 1` and you add 1 to `nmin` while `f(nmin)<=fmin`. To do that, you can use a `while` loop.

By doing `f(nmin)`, you call the function `f` and calculate its value for the entry `nmin`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! When I try the second code example (i.e. `f(n) = n**2 + 6*n - 3` I get the output `21` instead of `20`, do you know why that might be?

Comment: @codemachine98, *please* instead of blindly using code, spend one minute to figure this out for yourself. Ask yourself: is `f(nmin) < fmin` really the opposite of `f(nmin) > fmin`?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I edited my answer to correct this fact.

Answer (score -1):

```
def f(n):
    return 2*n
def lowest_integer(f, fmin):
    for findmin in range(fmin):
        if f(findmin) > fmin:
            return findmin
    return -1
print(lowest_integer(f, 10))
```

Comment: I appear to get the message `TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer` when I input a floating number for fmin such as `fmin=1.5`. I tried setting `range(int(fmin))` but I don't get the right output